# Two microalias in single umbraco.library:RenderMacroContent method

Tags: xslt, umbraco, xslt-1.0, umbraco-blog

For the desktop site I have a content in Umbraco where `<p><?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="StoryDesc" /></p>` refers to XSLTName field

I am making a call from one XSLT to **StroyDesc** XSLT as

```
<xsl:variable name="StoryXSLT" select="$currentPage/XSLTName"/>

<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderMacroContent(StoryXSLT, $currentPage/id)" />
```

Now for mobile site I have different XSLT **MobileStoryDesc** instead of **StoryDesc**. I cannot add a new separate content like `<p><?UMBRACO_MACRO macroAlias="MobileStoryDesc" /></p>`. But I can alter the existing content without affecting the present desktop site.

Is it possible to make a XSLT call. Please suggest me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might not quite understand you, so apologies if I'm mixed up.

Why not create a MobileStoryXSLT & a DesktopStoryXSLT and use the StoryDescXSLT to choose which one to use?

Something like:

```
<xsl:if test="...desktop...">
   <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderMacroContent(DesktopStoryXSLT, $currentPage/id)" />
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="... mobile ...">
    <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:RenderMacroContent(MobileStoryXSLT, $currentPage/id)" />
</xsl:if>
```